# Scroll when rubber band reaches edge of panel

Tags: c#, scroll, panel, rubber-band

I have a rubber band that captures the cursor. How can I scroll a panel if the cursor reaches the edge of the panel? Let me know if you need more info, I think it explains itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the MouseMove event and check if the button is down and the cursor is located close to the edge of the panel.  Say within 5 pixels.  Enable a timer if that's the case, it should tick at ~200 msec.  In the Tick event handler adjust the panel's AutoScrollPosition property to make it scroll.

Keep in mind that the effective mouse position is e.Location plus AutoScrollPosition.

Comment: how would you adjust the AutoScrollPosition? AutoScrollPosition.X += 10 or something?

Comment: Yes, roughly.  That code won't compile but you've got the idea.  Negative values cause scrolling.  Set AutoScrollMinSize if necessary to make the scroll bars appear.